# Bash command within a git post-update hook is not found

Tags: git, bash, amazon-ec2, terminal, githooks

I have the following code in a git post-update hook that `cd`'s into my working directory and pulls from the bare git repo where this git hook lives:

```
cd $HOME/www/firefly

unset GIT_DIR

git pull hub master

combine

npm rebuild

exec git update-server-info
```

The problem is that when it runs `combine`, I get:

```
hooks/post-update: line 14: combine: command not found
```

The weird thing is that if I manually cd into my working directory and run `combine` it successfully executes the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `combine` a program stored in the `$HOME/www/firefly` directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combine isn't a shell command.  You likely need the full path or `./combine` if it's in the same directory.

The reason for the error is your path is different when running the script.